# Undefined behaviour of GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have created a `GridLayout(3,2)` in Java and inserted 6 `JLabel` components. They should be inserted in order of the code written, but they are arranged in descending order. Why?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Summary_Graph_JPanel1 extends JPanel {
    public Summary_Graph_JPanel1() {
        GridLayout g=new GridLayout(3,2);
        setLayout(g);
        add(new JLabel("1"),JLabel.CENTER);
        add(new JLabel("2"),JLabel.CENTER);
        add(new JLabel("3"),JLabel.CENTER);
        add(new JLabel("4"),JLabel.CENTER);
        add(new JLabel("5"),JLabel.CENTER);
        add(new JLabel("6"),JLabel.CENTER);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `JLabel.CENTER` is in the wrong place. It should be within the `JLabel` constructor rather than handed to the `add(JLabel, constraint)` method. It is not an appropriate constraint of the layout, but of the label.

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Summary_Graph_JPanel1 extends JPanel {
    public Summary_Graph_JPanel1() {
        GridLayout g=new GridLayout(3,2);
        setLayout(g);
        add(new JLabel("1",JLabel.CENTER));
        add(new JLabel("2",JLabel.CENTER));
        add(new JLabel("3",JLabel.CENTER));
        add(new JLabel("4",JLabel.CENTER));
        add(new JLabel("5",JLabel.CENTER));
        add(new JLabel("6",JLabel.CENTER));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Summary_Graph_JPanel1());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that the code I posted in reply is a [mre]. It is ready to compile and run as copy/pasted. My answer would have been sooner if the original code had been an MRE. (And there are times I will not even attempt to answer questions with no MRE - you caught me at a time when I was prepared to go the extra effort.)

Comment: @user16320675 Until you realise that the index is being used as a layout constraint, probably best to leave it to those more experienced.

Comment: @user16320675 *"more explicitly:.."* I'll read more when you post that as an answer with code and a screenshot of the result.